# Storing the last time Tweets got updated from API in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I'm new on iOS development and I got a problem with storing the last time Tweets got updated from API in iOS?

I want to retrieve tweets after the last time I retrieved and what is the best practice for getting the time my app retrieving tweets? Store it somewhere or get the latest tweets from core data(I store tweets in core data)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `since` and `until` operator.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&inc‌​lude_rts=true&screen_name=your_screen_name&since:2011-05-16&until:2011-08-16
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant how to store this info in applications. I just found the answer. Use NSUserDefaults. But I still thank you for your answer!